# Making a non-thread safe queue thread safe

Tags: java, thread-safety, queue

Say I have a queue implementation which is not thread safe. How can I make it thread safe (without modifying original code)? In other words:

How can I write a SynchronizedQueueWrapper which is backed by a regular non-thread safe queue?

Plus: My queue does not implement Collection interface besides add, remove, peek and size functions.

Answer (score 2):

If your queue implements `Collection`, you can simply use a `Collections.synchronizedCollection(queue);`. Otherwise I suggest you checked [the code of `synchronizedCollection`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.synchronizedCollection%28java.util.Collection%29) and did something similar (essentially: guarding all operations on the queue by a mutex on `this`).

Note that it will still require the users to properly access the synchronized queue, for example during iteration.

Comment: May I ask, Why does it need to synchronize add() method?

Comment: @user1186523 All methods need to be synchronized - if you have two threads adding at the same time it could corrupt the non thread safe collection. Similarly, if one thread adds and another reads later on, without synchronizing the `add` method, the second thread may not see the addition (stale data).